# Cound not find the correct Provider above this consumer Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm trying use multiprovider from library Provider.
But it's not working because it's can't find correct provider althought the upper widget before material is MultiProvider.

I Already try to import anything but it's still not working

```dart
class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<LoginModel>(
      builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<Chat>(
              stream: Provider.of<Socketio>(context).streamChat,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.data?.toString() ?? 'Foo');
              },
            ),
            LoginHeader(
              validationMessage: model.errorMessage,
              controller: _controller),
            model.state == ViewState.Busy
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
```

that is where I canll Provider.of

````dart
void main() {
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>(
          initialData: User.initial(),
          builder: (context) => locator<AuthenticationService>().userController,
        ),
        StreamProvider<Chat>(
          initialData: Chat.initial(),
          builder: (context) => locator<Socketio>().chatController,
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(),
        initialRoute: '/login',
        onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}```
this is where I provider socket io provider before Maetrialapp inside Multi Provider
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are doing:

```
Provider.of<Socketio>(context)
```

But you are never creating a provider of type `Provider<Socketio>`

Looking at your code, you likely want to use:

```
Provider.of<Chat>(context)
```

Comment: `class Socketio {
  StreamController<Chat> chatController = StreamController();
  Stream<Chat> streamChat;
`
And I have this for constructor
`Socketio() {
    initSocket();
    streamChat = chatController.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  }`

this is why Socketio class.

I want to have StreamController from SocketIO class with object type class

Comment: Yes, but in your `main` file, you are not exposing `Socketio` directly, You are exposing `Sockerio.streamChat` through `StreamProvider`.

Comment: I want to use StreamProvider not provider

Comment: Like I said, replace `.of<Socketio>` with `.of<Chat>` and it will work. You don't need the stream builder when using `StreamProvider`.

Comment: Chat class doesn't have streamChat field (it give me error like this if im using `.of<Chat>`

I want using stream builder so if I got new response from socket io, the chat automatically rebuild

Comment: You don't need to access `streamChat`. That's already taken care of. I'm the maintainer of the package you're using, and I can assure you that you want to use `.of<Chat>`.

Comment: Would you give me example of using StreamProvider?
You say to not use stream builder but in the example of the project, that using StreamBuilder
https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/example/provider.dart

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally understand what do you mean.
So I just need to use `newText(Provider.of<Chat>(context).sender`
then I can just `chatController.add(newChat())` in the SocketIo class to update the value.